# Efficient simultaneous rendering of multiline-texts in iOS/OSX

Tags: swift, uikit, core-animation, core-text, textkit

In a canvas-like UIScrollview which includes zoom functionality I am trying to render a number of TextFields ( 20-100 on larger screens) with on average 2-3 lines in a custom font while zooming. Editing and selecting is only required at 100% zoom-level. Still currently using a UITextView for everything.
That seems to work depending on the hardware with little lags (1-2s with 50 textfields on an ipad) but could definitely be improved. Each time The texts are rendered they may adjust their font size etc.

[image: Multiple TextFields on UIScrollView]

What is the recommended approach to handle this? I have tried out:

1. SpriteKit: very cumbersom to handle multiline text and tough when it comes to selection at some points. Does not play well with the surrounding UIKit  environment
2. UILabel: no major improvement to UITextView in speed
3. CATextLayer: also cumbersome with multiline. Still a considerable option(?)

Things which might be worth looking into(?):

1. CoreText: Can this improve performance significantly?
2. UIStringDrawing: is this compatible with UIViews and exact positioning in a bigger view hierachy?

Any other suggestions to make it play well?
For the Web we managed to realize this kind of Text rendering using the HTML5 canvas which is going quite smooth.

Comment: You should definitely not get a 2 second lag when rendering 50 `UILabel`s.

Comment: There's *much* difference between HTML5 and Swift. Yet you haven't really given us much in terms of *what* you've done. As mentioned, getting a 2 second lag with rendering 50 `UILabels` is a sign that you already are doing something wrong. Show us your code - maybe we can improve it from there.